# Jointables multiple times abc

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-columns

- I want different numbers like Credit,Funding, App, ClosingDate for
  loan_officer.
- I have a table [E].[dbo].[Main] on which I am applying different filters and 
  then trying to join them. This Main table has GUID as primary key.

Please suggest how should I join these tables.

```
    Select A.loan_officer, A.OrganizationId, [C].Credit as Credit,      
    [P].Application as 'App', [F].Funding as Fund, [B].ClosingDate as Brok      
    from

    --Credit Pulls     
    (SELECT Credit
    FROM  [E].[dbo].[Main]
    where Loan_Officer is not null
    and LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline')) as [C], 

    --Application Units
    (SELECT Application
    FROM  [E].[dbo].[Main]
    where loan_Officer is not null
    and LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline')
    and Denial_Date is null ) as [P],

    --Funding Units      
    (SELECT Funding
    FROM  [E].[dbo].[Main]
    where loan_Officer is not null
    and LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline')
    and Denial_Date is null) as [F],

    -- Brokered Units 
    (SELECT ClosingDate
    FROM [E].[dbo].[Main]
    where loan_Officer is not null
    and LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline')
    and Loan_Info_Channel_F2626 like 'Brok%'
    ) as [B],

    [E].[dbo].[Main] A     
    Join  [B] on B.ClosingDate_748 =A.ClosingDate_748        
    Join F on F.Funding_Date= A.Funding_Date         
    Join P on A.Application_Date= A.Application_Date               
    Join C on C.Credit_Pull_Date = A.Credit_pull_date
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can use a case statement here instead of these sub queries. sample data and expected otuput would help

Comment: Thanks for your response, as far as I know case can be applied on single column having multiple conditions. But in my case I have multiple columns requiring multiple filters. Please suggest.

Comment: What happens if, for  a specific row, one column passes the filter and the other doesn't? Show both? Show none? Show the one that passes, and the other with NULL?

Comment: Why wouldn't you include your PK (GUID) in your derived tables and LEFT join on it?  I'm obviously missing something though.

Comment: Actually it is GUID, so I am skeptical.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1` needs to be in each of those subqueries. Personally I rarely use subqueries like this. I prefer joins

Comment: @JoePhillips these are joins.  The subqueries are derrived tables being used in the last grouping joining the data. but it's all overkill since it's all from the same source table.

Comment: No sweat Shenk @xQert hooked you up below

Comment: @xQbert Oh dear god. Didn't even notice that... ouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xQbert did the hard work on this, I would just expand on it just a little to pull out the common search criteria so that you could do a little indexing and not just scan the entire table. I also just cleaned up some of the columns in the case statement to return the right data:

```
SELECT Loan_officer
     , OrganizationID
     ,Credit
     , CASE WHEN Denial_date is null  THEN [Application] ELSE NULL END as App
     , CASE WHEN Denial_date is null  THEN Funding else NULL end as Fund
     , CASE WHEN Loan_Info_Channel_F2626 like 'Brok%' THEN ClosingDate ELSE NULL end as Brok
FROM  [E].[dbo].[Main]
WHERE Loan_officer IS NOT NULL AND LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline')
```

Comment: You know I should have done that.   Great catch; and it's why development is iterative, you get better more complete each time.  I did something I laughed, I forgot to do it better. Technically we don't need the else nulls... if we wanted to improve readability :P  and @scsimon really had the first approach I just typed it up.

Comment: Thank you so much guys .. It worked, you guys are awesome. Sorry for my negligence before @xQbert.

Comment: Glad it worked, please mark it as answered if it did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with scsimon here...  no joins needed just use multiple case statements; one for each column you presently have as a derived table.

```
SELECT Loan_officer
     , OrganizationID
     , CASE WHEN Loan_officer is not null and 
       LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline') THEN Credit else NULL end as Credit
     , CASE WHEN Loan_officer is not null and 
       LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline') and
       Denial_date is null  THEN Credit else NULL end as Apps
     , CASE WHEN Loan_officer is not null and 
       LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline') and
       Denial_date is null  THEN Credit else NULL end as Funding as Fund,
     , CASE WHEN Loan_officer is not null and 
       LOANFOLDER IN ('Pipeline', 'Prospect', 'Employee Pipeline') and
       Loan_Info_Channel_F2626 like 'Brok%' THEN ClosingDate else NULL end as Brok
FROM  [E].[dbo].[Main]
```

Comment: Corrected some typos and bad spacing

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like the querying style. But my problem is I want output in columns as OrganizationID, Credit, Apps, Brok, Fund. But case would yield only one value.

Comment: @Shenk perhaps you should look at the query. This **IS** returning those columns. There is more than one case expression and more than one column being returned.

Comment: Nod.  6 columns are being  returned count the comma's add 1.   Loan_officer, organizationID, Credit, Apps, Fund, Brok